# Difference between two strings in VBScript

Tags: string, vbscript, difference

I need a way to find the difference between two strings in a Windows application using `VBScript`. One of the strings is known but the second one is completely unknown during coding. I know there are functions like `StrCompare`, `InStr` etc. but these require you to know the second string also during coding.

Explanation:

There is a text box in the screen and there are several buttons in the same screen. As and when the buttons are clicked, the text in the text box changes depending on the button clicked. Is there a way to find the changes made to the text after the button is clicked ? Basically I need to get the text entered due to the button click. Is there a simple way to do this or it requires complex coding ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Define "difference". Do you need to find the first non-matching character, [string similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_similarity) (e.g. the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)) or something else?

Comment: Let's say Initially the text box displayed "Apple". Once the user clicks a button, the text changes to "Apple, Orange". Now I need a way to find the text "Orange" alone.

Comment: There is no simple solution for finding arbitrary differences between two strings. Will the new text always be appended? Or will it be inserted at an arbitrary position in the existing string?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your application and the format of the new string.

If you need to find the text *appended* to the original string, you could take the new text and simply replace the first occurrence of the original string with an empty string:

```
Dim strOld, strNew, strDiff

strOld = "Apple"
strNew = "Apple, Orange"

strDiff = Replace(strNew, strOld, "", 1, 1)
WScript.Echo strDiff
```

Sample output:

> , Orange

Or if you need to get the appended text without the preceding comma, you could use something like this:

```
strDiff = Replace(strNew, strOld + ", ", "", 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

To access (read/write) the content of a HTML text input you need to get the HTML element `(document.all.<Name/Id> or document.getElementById(<Name/Id>)` and its .value; as in this demo:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <Title>readtext</Title>
  <hta:application id="readtext" scroll = "no">
  <script type="text/vbscript">
   Function Change()
     document.all.txtDemo.value = "Changed Value"
   End Function

   Function Check()
     Dim txtDemo : Set txtDemo = document.getElementById("txtDemo")
     Dim sDemo   : sDemo       = txtDemo.value
     Select Case LCase(Trim(sDemo))
       Case "initial value"
         MsgBox "still: " & sDemo
       Case "changed value"
         MsgBox "now: " & sDemo
       Case Else
         MsgBox "surpise: " & sDemo
     End Select
   End Function
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="text" id="txtDemo" value="Initial Value" />
  <hr />
  <input type="button" value="Change" onclick="Change" />
  <input type="button" value="Check"  onclick="Check"  />
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I am working on a windows application and not a webpage. Besides, I need to find the appended text alone.